# change UIView Position after load in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have two views in different positions and I need once the use click the button change the positions of them. I tried many options but it did not work. Any help?

```
firstView.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 1, height: 1)
SecondCiew.frame = CGRect(x: 63, y: 172, width: 217, height: 40)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: No I'm not I will make storeyboard for each device.